# Hiding a Singular Column of a series in a stacked column chart

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I currently have a VBA script which generates a combined chart from some data. My manager has requested that the "grand total" column (a sum of all the other columns) be present in the data table below. However, he does not want it present in the graph itself. I know that were I doing this manually, I would be able to double-click the circled column and set its Fill to "No Fill," but I cannot figure how how to do this in VBA. Note I am not trying to hide the entire series, just the circled column in the picture below.

What I have:

[Picture of Incorrect Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEYOV.png)

What I'm trying to accomplish:

[Picture of Corrected Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4olpe.png)

Thanks for your time!

EDIT: Plotting Code:

```
'Plotting!
Dim dblMax As Double
dblMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(dpws.Range("B2:P4"))
Dim chrt As Chart
Set chrt = pws.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
With chrt
    .ChartArea.Left = 200
    .ChartArea.Top = 0
    .ChartArea.Height = 500
    .ChartArea.Width = 800
    .Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
    .ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    .HasDataTable = True
    .SetSourceData Source:=dpws.UsedRange
    .SeriesCollection("Forecasted % Complete").AxisGroup = 2
    .SeriesCollection("Forecasted % Complete").ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    .SeriesCollection("Forecasted % Complete").MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleSquare
    .SeriesCollection("Cumulative").ChartType = xlLine
    .SeriesCollection("Cumulative").Format.Line.Visible = False
    .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
    .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = dblMax + dblMax * 0.2
    .Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MinimumScale = 0
    .Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MaximumScale = 1
End With
```

And below you will find the full code.

```
Sub MyCode()
Dim dws As Worksheet
Dim pws As Worksheet
Dim start As Range
Dim dataRange As Range
Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim startPvt As String
Dim lastCol As Integer

'Create ChartBin, ChartDate columns.
Set dws = Sheets("Sheet1")
With dws
    lastCol = dws.Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    .Cells(1, lastCol + 1).Value = "Chart_Bin"
    .Cells(1, lastCol + 2).Value = "Chart_Date_Group"
End With


'Populate Chart Columns
Dim i As Long
Dim thisMonth As Integer
Dim hwswDateCol As Long
Dim statusCol As Long
Dim hwswDateGrpCol As Long
hwswDateCol = 162
statusCol = 13
hwswDateGrpCol = 163 'Really should search for these column titles.
thisMonth = Month(Date)
With dws
    For i = 2 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count Step 1
        .Cells(i, lastCol + 2).Value = .Cells(i, hwswDateGrpCol).Value
        'If complete...
        If (.Cells(i, statusCol) = "Complete") Then
            .Cells(i, lastCol + 1).Value = "Complete"
        'If not complete, date passed...
        ElseIf (thisMonth - Month(.Cells(i, hwswDateCol)) > 0) Then
            .Cells(i, lastCol + 1).Value = "Missed"
        Else
            .Cells(i, lastCol + 1).Value = "Forecasted"
        End If
    Next i
End With

'Copy just data we need to reduce pivot size.
Set rws = Sheets.Add
rws.Name = "Raw"
dws.Columns(1).Copy Destination:=rws.Columns(1)
dws.Columns(2).Copy Destination:=rws.Columns(2)
dws.Columns(4).Copy Destination:=rws.Columns(3)
dws.Columns(8).Copy Destination:=rws.Columns(4)
dws.Columns(10).Copy Destination:=rws.Columns(5)
dws.Columns(22).Copy Destination:=rws.Columns(6)
dws.Columns(131).Copy Destination:=rws.Columns(7)
dws.Columns(11).Copy Destination:=rws.Columns(8)
dws.Columns(101).Copy Destination:=rws.Columns(9)
dws.Columns(lastCol + 1).Copy Destination:=rws.Columns(10)
dws.Columns(lastCol + 2).Copy Destination:=rws.Columns(11)


'Create pivots.
Set pws = Sheets.Add
pws.Name = "Pivot"
Set start = rws.Range("A1")
Set dataRange = rws.Range(start, start.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
startPvt = pws.Name & "!" & pws.Range("T1").Address(ReferenceStyle:=x1R1C1)
Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=dataRange)
Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=startPvt, TableName:="Market Totals")
pvt.PivotFields("Chart_Date_Group").Orientation = xlColumnField
pvt.PivotFields("Chart_Bin").Orientation = xlRowField
pvt.PivotFields("JOB NUMBER").Orientation = xlDataField

'Add slicers.
Dim sl As Slicer
Dim sls As Slicers
Dim slcs As SlicerCaches
Dim slc As SlicerCache
Set slcs = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches
Set sls = slcs.Add(pws.PivotTables(1), "Carrier Type", "Carrier_Type").Slicers
Set sl = sls.Add(pws, , "Carrier_Type", "Carrier Type", 0, 0, 200, 75)
Set sls = slcs.Add(pws.PivotTables(1), "AVP", "AVP").Slicers
Set sl = sls.Add(pws, , "AVP", "AVP Type", 75, 0, 100, 250)
Set sls = slcs.Add(pws.PivotTables(1), "MARKET_RPA", "MARKET_RPA").Slicers
Set sl = sls.Add(pws, , "MARKET_RPA", "MARKET_RPA", 75, 100, 100, 400)
Set sls = slcs.Add(pws.PivotTables(1), "Driver", "Driver").Slicers
Set sl = sls.Add(pws, , "Driver", "Driver", 325, 0, 100, 150)
Set sls = slcs.Add(pws.PivotTables(1), "VENDOR", "VENDOR").Slicers
Set sl = sls.Add(pws, , "VENDOR", "VENDOR", 475, 0, 100, 150)
Set sls = slcs.Add(pws.PivotTables(1), "Hardware Location", "Hardware_Location").Slicers
Set sl = sls.Add(pws, , "Hardware_Location", "Hardware Location", 475, 100, 100, 200)
Set sls = slcs.Add(pws.PivotTables(1), "IWOS Flag", "IWOS_Flag").Slicers
Set sl = sls.Add(pws, , "IWOS_Flag", "IWOS Flag", 675, 0, 200, 125)

'Add data to data prep worksheet.
Dim dpws As Worksheet
Set dpws = Sheets.Add
dpws.Name = "Data Prep"
dpws.Cells(2, 1).Value = "Complete"
dpws.Cells(3, 1).Value = "Forecasted"
dpws.Cells(4, 1).Value = "Missed"
dpws.Cells(5, 1).Value = "Cumulative"
dpws.Cells(6, 1).Value = "Forecasted % Complete"
dpws.Cells(1, 2).Value = "2015"
dpws.Cells(1, 3).Value = "2016 Jan"
dpws.Cells(1, 4).Value = "2016 Feb"
dpws.Cells(1, 5).Value = "2016 Mar"
dpws.Cells(1, 6).Value = "2016 Apr"
dpws.Cells(1, 7).Value = "2016 May"
dpws.Cells(1, 8).Value = "2016 Jun"
dpws.Cells(1, 9).Value = "2016 Jul"
dpws.Cells(1, 10).Value = "2016 Aug"
dpws.Cells(1, 11).Value = "2016 Sep"
dpws.Cells(1, 12).Value = "2016 Oct"
dpws.Cells(1, 13).Value = "2016 Nov"
dpws.Cells(1, 14).Value = "2016 Dec"
dpws.Cells(1, 15).Value = "2017"
dpws.Cells(1, 16).Value = "2018"

For i = 2 To dpws.UsedRange.Columns.Count Step 1
    dpws.Cells(2, i).Value = WorksheetFunction.IfError(pvt.GetPivotData("JOB NUMBER", "Chart_Bin", "Complete", "Chart_Date_Group", dpws.Cells(1, i).Value), 0)
    dpws.Cells(3, i).Value = WorksheetFunction.IfError(pvt.GetPivotData("JOB NUMBER", "Chart_Bin", "Forecasted", "Chart_Date_Group", dpws.Cells(1, i).Value), 0)
    dpws.Cells(4, i).Value = WorksheetFunction.IfError(pvt.GetPivotData("JOB NUMBER", "Chart_Bin", "Missed", "Chart_Date_Group", dpws.Cells(1, i).Value), 0)
Next i
dpws.Cells(1, 17).Value = "Grand Total"
dpws.Cells(2, i) = pvt.GetPivotData("JOB NUMBER", "Chart_Bin", "Complete")
dpws.Cells(3, i) = pvt.GetPivotData("JOB NUMBER", "Chart_Bin", "Forecasted")
dpws.Cells(4, i) = pvt.GetPivotData("JOB NUMBER", "Chart_Bin", "Missed")
dpws.Cells(5, i) = pvt.GetPivotData("JOB NUMBER")



'Calculate percentages/cumulatives.
Dim grandTotalCol As Integer
Dim percentageRow As Integer
Dim sumRow As Integer
Dim prevValue As Double
prevValue = 0
grandTotalCol = i
sumRow = 5
percentageRow = 6

With dpws
    For i = 2 To dpws.UsedRange.Columns.Count Step 1
        .Cells(sumRow, i).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(4, i))) + prevValue
        prevValue = .Cells(sumRow, i).Value
        If i = dpws.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1 Then
            prevValue = 0
        End If
        .Cells(percentageRow, i).Value = dpws.Cells(sumRow, i).Value / dpws.Cells(5, grandTotalCol).Value
        .Cells(percentageRow, i).NumberFormat = "0%"
    Next i
End With

'Plotting!
Dim dblMax As Double
dblMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(dpws.Range("B2:P4"))
Dim chrt As Chart
Set chrt = pws.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
With chrt
    .ChartArea.Left = 200
    .ChartArea.Top = 0
    .ChartArea.Height = 500
    .ChartArea.Width = 800
    .Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
    .ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    .HasDataTable = True
    .SetSourceData Source:=dpws.UsedRange
    .SeriesCollection("Forecasted % Complete").AxisGroup = 2
    .SeriesCollection("Forecasted % Complete").ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    .SeriesCollection("Forecasted % Complete").MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleSquare
    .SeriesCollection("Cumulative").ChartType = xlLine
    .SeriesCollection("Cumulative").Format.Line.Visible = False
    .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
    .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = dblMax + dblMax * 0.2
    .Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MinimumScale = 0
    .Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MaximumScale = 1
End With



End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Done! The plotting stuff is likely the most relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just added 2 lines of code to your original 'Plotting Section

```
Dim dblMax As Double
dblMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(dpws.Range("B2:P4"))
Dim chrt As Chart
Set chrt = pws.Shapes.AddChart.Chart

With chrt
    .ChartArea.Left = 200
    .ChartArea.Top = 0
    .ChartArea.Height = 500
    .ChartArea.Width = 800
    .Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
    .ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    .HasDataTable = True
    .SetSourceData Source:=dpws.UsedRange
    .SeriesCollection("Forecasted % Complete").AxisGroup = 2
    .SeriesCollection("Forecasted % Complete").ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    .SeriesCollection("Forecasted % Complete").MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleSquare
    .SeriesCollection("Cumulative").ChartType = xlLine
    ' Added the 2 lines below
    .SeriesCollection("Cumulative").Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
    .SeriesCollection("Cumulative").Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
    .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = dblMax + dblMax * 0.2
    .Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MinimumScale = 0
    .Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MaximumScale = 1
nd With
```

Comment: Massively appreciate the feedback Shai. I eventually found a solution using the .points method, but yours is cleaner.